# disable system.out.print logs from logcat

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a way to disable the system.out.print logs from logcat?

I have disabled Log.v statements using progaurd. Is there a similar approach for sys outs too? There are a lot of such statements used in the app. Pls help...

Comment: Is is acceptable to [filter](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) out those logs?

Comment: need to filter them out, when releasing the build..

Answer (score 0):

One way is, go to file search in eclipse, type in 'System.out.print' and replace by '//System.out.print' .

It replaces all sys outs across the project.. ;)

Comment: What about system.out by other applications? If you are just asking about your own application, then it is really a very simple question.

Comment: I thought there was a better approach rather than commenting every sysout... And what about other applications? you could work out the same for other apps too.. rite?